# Reading custom format files in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I would like to fetch n bytes from specific place in a file into my 
specific data structure (a struct).

The old C - application (which we are porting) uses fseek() and fread().

Is where a comparable solution in C#/.Net, without using the Win32-API?

Answer (score 5):

I'd use the [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream_methods.aspx) class, and then the `Seek` + `Read` methods and `Position` property.

Comment: To add, wrap a `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` around that stream for the conversion between primitive types and byte arrays.

Comment: The performance is really important. I would like to read a whole struct like in the old c++ application. For example

Comment: The performance is really important. I would like to read a whole struct like in the old c++ application. Like this:
fread(&s, sizeof(SDataRecord), 1, file);  My DataRecord contains variables of different primitive types and also 'subrecords'. I have a problem with performance: in the c- application reading a record is one IO operation.

Comment: I think, using Win32 APi is my only option.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest since you are porting a C application to a C# application that you store data in objects, not structs, unless you really care about overhead performance.